# Python3 in subprocess.check_output uses python2.7

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, subprocess, mpc

I have a script managing mpc-commands with python3. I use subprocess.check_output to get information:

```
s = (subprocess.check_output("mpc current -f %title%", shell=True,encoding = 'utf-8'))
```

That works well and gives me the value as a string.

Trying to install a service for the script fails with the error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 216, in check_output
 process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'
```

Same result (working script, failing service) with 'text = true' instead of 'encoding = 'utf8''.

Why is python2.7 used for subprocess instead of python3?
In the seccond line of the script I have

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Version of Python is 3.7.3

Comment: Apparently you are using Python 2.7. What's the output of `import sys; print(sys.version_info)` and `print(sys.executable)`?

Comment: sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
shebang is #!/usr/bin/python3

Comment: sys_executable: /usr/bin/python3

Comment: What do you mean by *"Trying to install a service for the script"*? Did you check these values inside the script that produces the error?

Comment: I installed a service and run systemctl start mpctask.service. Then I run systemctl status mpctask.service with the error above. - I got it to run by using universal_newlines=True instead of encoding=utf8. But why python2.7 is used for the subprocess? The system is updated, and subprocess.py is in present in /usr/lib/python3.7

Comment: Can you add the code for the service (i.e. `cat mpctask.service`)? Can you add the logging information of `sys.*` to the script run by the service as well and then check via `journalctl`? I suppose the service is run on Python 2.7 instead of Python 3.

Comment: I overlooked that in the service task I wrote the ExecStart sequence with python instead of python3: 'ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/mpctask.py'. It is working now as expected and I hope that this was the mistake. Thanks for your advice, a_guest